# R Studio: Average multiple columns with conditional logic

Tags: r, conditional-statements, average, subset, mean

In R studio, how can I get one average of multiple columns with conditional logic for one of the columns? For example, I have a dataset, called 'test' of the below 5 columns. I want to get one combined average for columns A, B, and C. But I only want to include Column C in the average if Flag is equal to 1 for a cell in Column C.

```
    ID<-c(1,2,3)
    A<-c(1,0,NA)
    B<-c(0,NA,1)
    C<-c(1,1,1)
    Flag<-c(0,1,1)
   test<-as.data.frame(cbind(ID,A,B,C,Flag))
```

[[click here to see my data set]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vqs3V.png)

So I want: Average = (All cells in column A + All cells in column B + Only cells in column C where cells in Flag column is equal to 1 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We `unlist` the dataset with a subset of columns ("A", "B"), concatenate with the values of "C" that corresponds to "Flag" of 1 and get the `mean`.

```
mean(c(unlist(test[c("A", "B")]), test$C[test$Flag==1]), na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] 0.6666667
```

Comment: But this returns multiple averages for rows where Flag is equal to 1. I am trying to get one overall average of the matrix (columns A,B,C) that excludes cells in C where Flag is equal to zero.

Comment: @Smith Updated the post.  Check if this is the expected output.